# Simpler method of filtering array of object of array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter an array of objects which has objects of array of objects inside. For example, an object in an array would look like this.

```
list=[...,
    {
        "types": [
            {
            "slot": 2,
            "type": 
                {
                    "url": "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/",
                    "name": "poison"
                }
            },
            {
            "slot": 1,
            "type": 
                {
                    "url": "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/",
                    "name": "grass"
                }
            }
        ],
        "name": 'bulbasaur'
    },...
]
```

I'm currently filtering the list by its name and the types of objects like this (the this.props.search.search being a string, and the example being an example list of strings that will be adjusted):

```
    let filtered = this.props.pokemons.filter((pokemon)=>{
        return pokemon.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.search.search.toLocaleLowerCase())!==-1;
    })
    let example = ['fire', 'ice', 'water'];
    let filteredx= filtered.filter((pokemon)=>{
        return pokemon.types.filter((type)=>{
            return example.indexOf(type.type.name)!==-1
        }).length>0
    })
```

Is there a method of combining all the filters into one instead of calling

```
array.filter(...).filter(...)
```

As in the future, if more filters are added, I'm afraid that it's going to end up looking like

```
array.filter(...).filter(...).filter(...).filter(...).filter(...)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using `const` instead of `let` wherever possible. It makes your code more predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two conditions with an `&&`:

```
let filteredx = this.props.pokemons.filter(pokemon =>
    pokemon.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.props.search.search.toLocaleLowerCase())
    && pokemon.types.some(type => example.includes(type.type.name))
)
```

Note you can use `includes` and `some` in your conditions, and use the expression syntax in your arrow functions (without braces nor `return`).

You can add more conditions with additional `&&` operators. Make sure to put them in such order that the most simple conditions (that require least work) come first.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, but this one seemed like the one that I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If the array is small and perfomance not an issue;

```
const arryOfPokemons = [{name: 'name1', type: 'type1'}];

function name(pokemon) { return pokemon.name !== 'name' }

function type(pokemon) { return pokemon.type !== 'type' }

const result = [name, type].reduce((result, filterFunc) => result.filter(filterFunc), arryOfPokemons);
```

otherwise you can try to combine the conditions into the same filter function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering multiple times, you can combine all the filter conditions in one filter.

Instead of doing this...

```
let filtered1 = toFilter.filter((element) => {
    return condition1;
});

let filtered2 = filtered1.filter((element) => {
    return condition2;
});

...

let filteredN = filteredN_1.filter((element) => {
    return conditionN;
});
```

... you can combine the conditions in a single filter:

```
let filtered = toFilter.filter((element) => {
    return condition1 && condition2 && ... && conditionN;
});
```

If one of the conditions is very long, you can easily abstract it in a separate function. This also makes the code more readable and maintainable.

```
let filtered = toFilter.filter((element) => {
    const condition1 = computeCondition1(arg1, arg2);
    const condition2 = computeCondition2(arg1);
    ...
    const condition3 = computeCondition3(arg2, arg3, arg4);

    return condition1 && condition2 && ... && conditionN;
});
```

Comment: Why not `const` instead of `let`?

Answer (score 0):

You could define an object which contains a property for every first level property of your pokemon list you want to test. The value would be a predicate with the "test logic" for this property.

```js
const pokemons = [
  {"name":"poke1","types":[{"type":{"name":"poison"}},{"type":{"name":"grass"}}]},
  {"name":"poke2","types":[{"type":{"name":"fire"}},{"type":{"name":"grass"}}]},
  {"name":"poke3","types":[{"type":{"name":"ice"}},{"type":{"name":"water"}}]},
  {"name":"poke4","types":[{"type":{"name":"ice"}},{"type":{"name":"grass"}}]}
];

const filterOptions = {
  name: (name) => {
    return ["poke1", "poke5"].some(x => x === name);
  },
  types: (types) => {
    return ["ice", "water"].some(t => types.some(x => t === x.type.name));
  }
};

function filterList(list, options) {
  return list.filter(pokemon => {
    return Object.keys(options)
                 .some(key => {
                   if (key in pokemon) {
                     return filterOptions[key](pokemon[key]);
                   }
                 });
  });
}

const filtered = filterList(pokemons, filterOptions);
filtered.forEach(p => console.log(JSON.stringify(p)));
```